# Function problem replacing string characters

Tags: python-3.x

It works when I'm not using function.

```
def maskify(string):
    string = input("")
    i = len(string)
    if len(string)>i-4:

        for x in range(0,i-4):
          print('#', end ='')
        print(string[-4:])

    elif len(string)<=4:
        print(string[-4:])
```

expected output

input:Hello world 
output:#######orld

output must be in a storage named cc so that I could return the value.
return string

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the length is greater than 4

```
def maskify(string):
    if len(string)>4:
        for i in range(0,len(string)-4):
            print('#',end='')
        print(string[-4:])
    else:
        print(string[-4:])
maskify(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the def to `def maskify()` & when you run the function just use `maskify()`.

```
def maskify():
    string = input("")
    i = len(string)
    if len(string)>i-4:

        for x in range(0,i-4):
          print('#', end ='')
        print(string[-4:])

    elif len(string)<=4:
        print(string[-4:])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def maskify(cc):

    i = len(cc)
    temp=''
    if len(cc)>i-4:

        for x in range(0,i-4):
            temp='#'+temp
        cc=temp+cc[-4:]
        return cc
    elif len(cc)<=4:
        cc= cc[-4:]
        return cc

print(maskify("input"))
```

Thanks a lot guys :)